# HAXM cannot be installed

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

When I try to run my project pop a error message from emulator like
[image]

Then I try to install HAXM using **silent_install.bat**, it's appear error

> This computer does not support Intel Execute Disable Bit (XD) or it is
>   disable in the BIOS. HAXM cannot be installed.  Please refer to the
>   Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

Then I execute **silent_install.bat -c**

> VT support -- yes
>   NX support -- no

When I try to set it from BIOS, the VIRTULIZATION option is disabled, so I dont know how to fix it. Please give me some advice. Thanks.

This is my computer spesification:

> Operating System  : Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit 
>   CPU : Intel Core 2 Duo E6400 @ 2.13GHz Conroe 65nm Technology 
>   RAM : 2.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 333MHz (5-5-5-15) 
>   Motherboard : ASUSTeK Computer INC. P5LD2-SE (Socket 775)

When running using Intel Identification Utility
[image: This is my processor]

Comment: In BIOS did you have 'Execute Disable Function' to Enabled or True?

Comment: in BIOS : Virtualization Tech default to ENABLE, but this option is frozen, cannot change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the command 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn

Comment: thanks @codecats , i try to run the command under administator right and the operation is succesfully, but still got VT Support : Yes and NX Support : no while take to restart

Comment: why i cannot find HyperV in WIndows Features ?

Comment: what happened after the reboot?  It's the NX that is showing no, right? Plus why do you want hyper V (not included in Windows 7 by default), it has to be off for HAXM to run anyway.

Comment: Yes,  after reboot NX : no,  actually it  NX must on or off? just see other post they have HYPERV,

Comment: You need NX to be turned on for HAXM. You need VT-d  on (which is needed for HAXM and for Hyper V but only one can use it at a time which is why (if you had hyperV) you'd need to turn it off......Did you run the "bcedit /set nx always on" as admin?

Comment: Yes..  And then reboot, but NX still not changed

Comment: In your BIOS look for any of these names:
 NX or
 XD
No Execute Memory Protect
 Execute Disabled Memory Protection
 EDB (Execute Disabled Bit)<br>  or EVP (Enhanced Virus Protection). They are often under either Advanced or Security or a memory section.

Comment: Execute disable function : disable, virtualization technology : enabled ( when it coming unfrozen? ). So what should I do? Thanks before..

Comment: Thanks @codecatss .. It's fix after Execute Disable function set to enabled,  and now NX support : yes and instalation is successful.  Thanks again